# Find records with different sum in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
TABLE1
| [Key1] | [Key2] | [Key3] | Value1 | Value2 |
+ ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ +
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 100    | 100    |
| 1      | 1      | 2      | 100    | 100    |
| 1      | 1      | 3      | 100    | 100    |

TABLE1_DETAILED
| [Key1] | [Key2] | [Key3] | [Key4] | Value1 | Value2 |
+ ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ | ------ +
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 1      | 10     | 10     |
| 1      | 1      | 1      | 2      | 90     | 90     |
| 1      | 1      | 2      | 1      | 10     | 10     |
| 1      | 1      | 2      | 2      | 80     | 90     |
| 1      | 1      | 3      | 1      | 90     | 110    |
```

And I need to select records from Table1 where Value1 or Value2 is different than Sum of Values1 and/or Values2 from TABLE1_DETAILED with the same Key1, Key2 and Key3. Also I need value difference between the tables, for example above I need the query to return:

```
TABLE1_RESULT
| [Key1] | [Key2] | [Key3] | Value1 | Value2 |
+ ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ +
| 1      | 1      | 2      | 10     | 0      |
| 1      | 1      | 3      | 10     | -10    |
```

I tried to resolve this in so many ways but I miss something and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You indicate that you tried "many ways", but you haven't shown what you tried and what results you got. Please show your work so that someone can help with the specific issue you are having.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far. This will help people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [SQL 101](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/everything-about-group-by).

```
(SELECT Key1, Key2, Key3, SUM(Value1) AS Sum1, SUM(Value2) AS Sum2
FROM TABLE1_DETAILED
GROUP BY Key1, Key2, Key3) as TABLE1_SUMS
```

JOIN that with the first table WHERE Sum1<>Value1 OR Sum2<>Value2

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome. I combined too much with group by and having.